# How do I show $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b^2-a,b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> How do I show $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b^2-a,b)$?

I know that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$. I think the statement $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b^2-a,b)$ is false but im not finding any counterexample.

Comment: $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(-a,b) = \gcd (b^2-a, b)$

Comment: Going forward, for similar problems of this type, if you want to show that $(p,q) = (r,s)$, you do this as follows.  Let $d = (p,q)$ and let $(e) = (r,s).$   **To Show**: $d$ is a common divisor of $r$ and $s$, and $e$ is a common divisor of $p$ and $q$.  This will imply that $d|e$ and $e|d$.  Together, these two results will imply that $d = e$.

Comment: I didn't understand the last equality @peterwhy, could you explain what property did you use?

Comment: @user988677 By the same reason that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-b,b)$, repeat $b$ times and get $$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-b,b) = \gcd(a-2b,b) = \ldots = \gcd(a-b^2,b)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, if and only if $a=dr$ and $b=ds$ for some $r,s\in\Bbb Z$, if and only if $ma=drm$ and $nb=dsn$ for some $r,s\in\Bbb Z$ and all $m,n\in\Bbb Z$, if and only if $d \mid (ma+nb)$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: oh get it, so, I can take n=b and m=-1 and the statement follows right?

Comment: Exactly, @user988677.

Answer (score 0):

$gcd(a,b)|gcd(b^2-a,b)$ and by way of Bezouts's identity, we have that if $ma+nb=gcd(a,b)$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $m(b^2-a)+(n-mb)b=gcd(a,b)$ which shows that $gcd(b^2-a,b)|gcd(a,b)$.

Also,  $gcd(b^2-a,b)=gcd(b^2-b-a,b)=gcd(b^2-2b-a,b)=\cdots=gcd(b^2-b\times b-a,b)=gcd(-a,b)=gcd(a,b)$